# How to create an ElementMesh with at least two triangle elements at each corner?

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

Based on this simple example of a triangle mesh

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[] , "MaxCellMeasure" -> .05 ,"MeshElementType" ->"TriangleElement", "MeshOrder" -> 1]
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

I would like to ask the following question:

How can I force mathematica to create a triangle mesh with at least two elements at each corner?

Thanks!

Comment: I think I may not be understanding your question. Could you clarify (perhaps with a graphical example) what you mean by two triangle elements in each corner? Do you mean that the vertex of the enclosing square should be a vertex for *two* triangles, instead of one as it is above?

Comment: Sorry for need of clarification. The simpliest mesh I'm looking for would  consist of  rectangle +two diagonals.

Comment: I am not sure why TWO diagonals would be the simplest. Surely the simplest triangulation would only have ONE diagonal, i.e. dividing the rectangle into two triangles? That can be accomplished with a large enough value of `MaxCellMeasure`, e.g. `MaxCellMeasure -> 1`. I could not find any value for MaxCellMeasure that would give four triangles (i.e. both diagonals).

Comment: I can get the TWO diagonal version using `TriangulateMesh[Rectangle[], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.3]` if that helps

Comment: @MarcoB two diagonal version fullfills all four corner conditions

Comment: I have  a very vague recollection that this is not done because it is bad in some way, either for interpolation or PDE solving. Unfortunately, the memory cell containing the specifics to this has been lost unrecoverable. I have looked again in [What Is a Good Linear Finite Element](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/papers/elemj.pdf) but I did not find the relevant section - not even sure that is the correct source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get the desired outcome using the build in [`TriangulateMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TriangulateMesh.html):

```
TriangulateMesh[Rectangle[], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.3]
```

[image: a mesh of four triangles, from the square cut by both diagonals]

The best I could get with the FEM machinery is only one diagonal:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

ToElementMesh[
  Rectangle[], "MaxCellMeasure" -> 1,
  "MeshElementType" -> "TriangleElement", "MeshOrder" -> 1
 ]["Wireframe"]
```

[image: rectangle bisected by only one diagonal]

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. Still I would like to give a mesh constraint "Every meshpoint has at least 3 neighbors"

Answer (score 1):

You could try including more points near the corners. E.g.:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[], "MaxCellMeasure" -> .02, 
  "MeshElementType" -> "TriangleElement", "MeshOrder" -> 1, 
  "IncludePoints" -> {{0.1, 0.1}, {0.9, 0.9}}]
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Comment: Tahnks for this simple approach. But it depends sensitively on value of `MaxCellMeasure`. I tried  `"MaxCellMeasure" -> .04`  which gives unexpacted result

Comment: You could try to add additional points on the border near the corners.